# Copy Paste block data from a csv into another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

is there a way not to select workbook back and forth and copy a block of data efficiently?

this is how I am doing it right now:

```
Set MyWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set DataWS = MyWB.Worksheets("Data")
Set TermDataRange = DataWS.Range("celltopaste")

Workbooks("data.csv").Activate
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy  'selecting block data
MyWB.Activate
TermDataRange.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

is there a way without selecting MyWB, then the range?

also, selection.paste feels kind of wierd, I hate copying data to clipboard.

I was hoping for something like:

```
Workbooks("data.csv").Activate
TermDataRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: another option can be `Data` tab > `From Text` and in the Properties you can change when the data should be refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting the range directly is as easy as meshing your three lines together:

```
Set TermDataRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("celltopaste")
```

*edited - my mistake - I'd skipped more steps than I thought and was actually condensing three of your lines, rather than two, into one : )*

(to be honest I would never normally give a seperate name to ActiveWorkbook itself, unless I needed to refer to it as a workbook later in the code)

Avoiding Copy/Paste is pretty easy. The trick is to make sure that your source range and destination range are the same size and shape - once this is true you can simply use the code

```
RangeA.Value = RangeB.Value
```

In your case, your best bet is to measure the size of your data first. e.g.

```
'give range("A1").current region a name just to make it less unwieldy
CopyRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Datarows = CopyRange.Rows.Count
Datacols = CopyRange.Columns.Count
'set a range of same size starting from TermDataRange to move the values to
set DestRange = Range(TermDataRange, TermDataRange(offset(Datarows -1, Datacolumns -1))
'move values directly rather than via copy-paste
DestRange.Value = CopyRange.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something more "clean" like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyValueFromSheet()

    Dim MyWB As Workbook
    Dim DataWS As Worksheet
    Dim TermDataRange As Range
    Dim OtherWB As Workbook

    ' To avoid screen flashing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set MyWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataWS = MyWB.Worksheets("Sheetname")
    Set TermDataRange = DataWS.Range("DestinationCell")

    Set OtherWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop\CsvFileName.csv")
    ' When opening a csv file there is only one worksheet with the same name as the csv file
    OtherWB.Worksheets("CsvFileName").Range("SourceCell").Copy
    TermDataRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Another possible way would result in storing the value of the source cell in a VBA variable and then set it to the destination cell, but it will be pretty much the same:

```
    Dim VarValue As String
    VarValue = OtherWB.Worksheets("CsvFileName").Range("SourceCell").Value
    TermDataRange.Value = VarValue
```

HTH ;)

Comment: thanks definitely cleaner! Still trying to stop using clipboard! :)

Comment: I do not know other way than using `.Copy` if you are trying to get a specific cell and then copy its value. At least this way you avoid the use of `.Activate` and `.Select` :)

Comment: @StevenG, this way you do not use `.Copy` but it is pretty similar and will return the same results.